# Did Obito let Kakashi win?

Tags: naruto

So, during Obito and Kakashi's fight in the Kamui dimension, Obito gets a hole in his chest. After watching the episode, most of the viewers commented that Obito "was defeated" even though he had the Rinnegan. But wasn't it because Obito ***"let"*** Kakashi win to undo Madara's Seal (as we see in **chapter 675**, Obito gets to know about the seal and wishes to undo it) and become the Ten Tails Jinchuuriki? Also, I wanted to know that would Kakashi (a ***non-Uchiha and a non-Senju***) have been able to **actually** defeat Obito? Because during their fight, Obito didn't use *Izanagi* or even one *Rinnegan* ability (even though, just moments later, he seals the Ten Tails inside him with the Rinnegan). I am compelled to say this, but Obito's abilities are no joke.

Please provide a convincing answer to explain exactly what happened during the fight and what would've happened if Obito was really serious.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, he did. Though it was not completely intentional. Specifically, he need a hole through his heart, because Madara placed a Seal on his heart, which he planned on using to control him. Obito later noted that he could not become the 10-tailed Jinchuriki because of that Seal. So Obito forced Kakashi to use his Raikiri to pierce his heart, destroying the seal. However, it was not a simple, let him do it kind of deal.

The Wiki unfortunately leaves out most of these details, but the Curse Mark's Entry on the Wiki has some of them, it is called The [Forbidden Individual Cursed Tag](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Individual_Curse_Tag). It forced Obito to not betray Madara, so in that respect, Obito could not just let it happen. However, he could indirectly let it happen, by forcing it, and otherwise weakening himself so that he could not stop it. In the Kamui Dimension, he could not use his intangibility, which would have been his main and possibly only solid defense against Raikiri. He also restricted his Chakra usage, saving it for future battles in the war, rather than using it to win against Kakashi, as he used almost no ninjutsu, and almost no Rinnegan techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Obito definitely let Kakashi win because once he got the Rinnegan, he could use all the powers that Pain had, and Kakashi DIED after defeating only one Pain.

Comment: Yes, that is true, though it is a weak explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Of course he did. Obito is an Uchiha, so he possesses the Sharingan, and he even got the Rinnegan from Nagato. By the end of Shippuden, it's basically: Kurama, Sharingan, or you're weak.

Answer (score 0):

Obito does NOT have the same abilities as Pain. The only Rinnegan ability Obito has is to summon the Gedo statue. This, him having only one eye Rinnegan, he mentioned he doesn't have enough chakra to have both.

Secondly, in the fight between Obito vs Kakashi, they both were somewhat holding back until the end. Kakashi decided there was no reason with Obito to come back to the Leaf, so his Chidori was to kill Obito. Obito was seriously fighting but not to kill, and he saw an opening to kill Kakashi and still had his seal broken and he took it, but his rod wasn't enough to kill, and Obito didn't think Kakashi's Chidori almost kill him.